# Android FileLock...how to lock files from different processes

Tags: android, file, locking

I need to lock a text file that is read and written from three different android applications...so different processes.

I've tried to use channel lock() (exclusive mode) when writing and lock(0L, Long.MAX_VALUE, true) (shared) when reading the file.

Unfortunately this approach does not work...lock is always acquired when reading also when the writing lock is not yet released.

Are there suitable and working examples to solve this issue?
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: "Am I doing something wrong?" -- you are trying to have three independent applications work with the same text file at the same time. That qualifies as "something wrong" right there as far as I am concerned.

Comment: File locks are supposed to be there to solve these kind of problems. I dont think that three apps that do concurrent accesses to the same file is something to be considered wrong. Btw do you have any suggestion?

Comment: "I dont think that three apps that do concurrent accesses to the same file is something to be considered wrong" -- you are certainly welcome to your opinion. "do you have any suggestion?" -- sure. Have one app own the data. Have the other two apps communicate with the first app via any of the available IPC mechanisms built into Android, such as content providers, remote services (command or binding pattern), and broadcasts.

Comment: @CommonsWare : I think app never own data, user does. User might need different apps to process their data, those apps might not know each other. File is the most generic and easiest way to store data. So there are circumstances that different apps need to access the same file. That's why file lock is designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've solved it!
FileLocks are ok...my problem is that I was writing to an xml file using storeToXml that probably creates a brand new file...so new file descriptor is created and the lock property was probably lost.
Now I'm locking another dummy file instead of the one I'm reading and writing and everything works as expected.

Comment: Would you post some code to show the two cases(file descriptor lost and not lost), so that we can learn from?

Comment: It's hard for me now to go into that old code...the only thing I can tell you is that I ended by not locking the file I was writing but just using a different empty file as lock file. So I'm sure nobody is touching or modifying it until the lock is released.